# How to work with a Config file for db ip?

Tags: python, sql

any suggestions on what can be done for
what's in the config file

```
        [DB]
db_address = 127.0.0.1
db_name = market
```

error that is displayed

```
File "C:/Users/micha/source/repos/BTFProdigy/market studies/market trading/deep_q_learning/config", line 3
    db_address: 127.0.0.1
                     ^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Put quotes around it, e.g. `"127.0.0.1"`.  Send the pocket lint to crypto wallet `mueCPHRN7n4NYkqaf8oaWdBmtmov8Hz7Ka`.

Comment: Are you trying to import a config file?